Low budget D-list movie with werewolf, emo guy, and mystical girl of his dreams
This is one for the pros. I'm trying to identify this movie, not because it was good or because I want to re-watch it, but because it was one of the most steaming piles of cinematic crud that I'd ever seen in Netflix (or possibly Amazon Prime). I'll try my best to give the bits and pieces I remember.
So yes, it was streamed, either Netflix or Amazon Prime video. It was within the last 5 years, or so.
Opening title screens had a very anime-like quality, very CGI heavy and felt like a kind of video game production. The film used low quality CGI often for things like fire and magic stuff.
Early scenes had a girl being chased down by a wolf or wolves, and at least one of them transforming into his human form. One of the werewolves was a black guy. The wolves might have chosen a new alpha at this point; or there was some kind of transfer or establishment of werewolf authority.
Later there was a teen party scene where an emo 'Azn' dude (a white guy who wanted to look Asian) and his buddy were talking about the girls, and the emo dude was very much a introvert/nerd, being razzed by his buddy for it. This dude fell for a girl with some kind of mystical qualities. She showed up in his dreams, at first. And then later they'd  meet in reality.
There was a big fight scene between the black guy werewolf and one or two others, I think involving the emo dude and the mystical girl. The werewolf had some awful cheesy lines and over-the-top gloating & power-tripping. The emo dude may have been trying to save the girl from the werewolf. But I can't remember if he had any powers of his own. The girl did use some powers of some kind.
The dialogue was largely sloppy and half-baked; not immature or sophomoric, just really corny. The action was poorly done and the actors often sounded bored, except the werewolf who was sometimes way too enthusiastic, especially during the big fight.
This isn't meant to be a review, I'm just at a loss for more pertinent details. I hope that someone else out there has seen this and can relate.
